# Throw exception when there is no values in selected column (stored procedure)

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS raise;

CREATE PROCEDURE raise(@uld int)
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
BEGIN 
    SET @uld = (select ULD_ID from doctor_personal_details)
    IF(@uld = NULL) THEN
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = ' error occurred';
END;
```

I have column `ULD_ID` in `doctor_personal_details` and I need to display error message when there is no data in `ULD_ID`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is check whether any record exists with provided `uld` and `SIGNAL` error if there is none, e.g.:

```
BEGIN

DECLARE CNT INT;

SELECT COUNT(*) INTO CNT
FROM doctor_personal_details
WHERE ULD_ID = uld;

IF(C = 0) THEN 
  SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
  SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'No records exist with given uid';
ELSE
  SELECT 'Success' AS message;
END IF;

END
```

Comment: Thanks for ur reply,But my question is, When i call the particular integer, it search into ULD_ID column if that integer is exists means print success otherwise Throw exception

Comment: @gobi I have updated the answer, it will now print `Success` if a record exists.

Comment: thanks a lot but how to call this sp " CALL raise" is this correct

Answer (score 0):

> DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS raise1;
>
> CREATE PROCEDURE raise1
>
> (IN uld int)
>
> BEGIN
>
> DECLARE CNT INT;
>
> DECLARE MESSAGE_TEXT varchar(80);
>
> SELECT COUNT(*) INTO CNT
>
> FROM doctor_personal_details
>
> WHERE ULD_ID = uld;
>
> IF(CNT = 0) THEN
>
> ```
> SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
>
> SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'No records exist with given uid';
>
> ELSE
> ```
>
> SELECT 'Success' AS message;
>
> END IF;
>
> END;

**call raise1('3');**